# Can I partition my boot drive?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have 2 physical drives on my laptop, a 500 GB hard drive and a 120 GB SSD. I installed Ubuntu on the SSD, and it thus became my boot drive. I moved my /home folder to the hard drive because I have more space for my pictures, music, etc. Now I noticed that my SSD has only a few GB used up and I would like to use the rest of that space for games, software and maybe a virtual machine. My first instinct would be to partition this drive, but I'm not too sure. Any ideas on how I should proceed?

Comment: So install games and other software, not really sure why you want more partitions, and especially, how it would help. What exactly would you do with another partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running in the exact same way as me: SSD for the system, HDD for `/home`.

Under Linux, there is a difference between the `/boot` and the `/`. The former is a tiny fraction of the system, whereas the latter is everything else (in your case: excluding `/home`).

So your SSD is not only used for the `/boot` but also for `/tmp` (where temporary files get created) `/bin` where executables reside, ...  Basically, if you install software and games they're going to go to the SSD, and the save files will be going to your HDD.

For the full documentation head to [FileSystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) and download the PDF and read all about it.

### So don't do anything! You've got the perfect system!

Comment: Well, perfect:... After you've read the FSH Standard document you *might* want to repartition the drive and give /boot its own partition, or /tmp or... but I wouldn't go overboard with that as the more partitions, the more headaches of resizing etc you'll have!

Comment: Great thank you! I didn't know linux worked in that way, I'm still quite new to this stuff.

Comment: Actually, you made me think so I just posted this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/  (only read the answer to number 4 in your case)